# Getting a current timestamp when retrieving a Parse object id instead of actual id

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I have a getQuery in one of my android main activity where I retrieve all rows from a parse class. In that query, I do parseObject.getObjectId() and assign it to a string variable that belongs to an object.

In a separate activity, where I have a delete button, I do a getQeury again to find the parseObject through objectid so I can delete the row. However, I noticed that this deletion fails because in this second activity, the objectID string variable that belongs to an object is not a real objectID associated with parseObject. Instead, the string variable returns a timestamp of the current time.

here's the code I have so far:

```
//main activity where I get and set
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myParseClass");
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException findCall) {
                                if (findCall == null) {
                                    for (ParseObject p : list) {
                                        if(p.getObjectId() != null) mParseObjectId = p.getObjectId();
                                        mItems.add(new superCoolClass(mParseObjectId));
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    findCall.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

And:

```
//second activity where i have delete button to delete parseObject from row
mDeleteItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myParseClass");
                    query.getInBackground(superCoolClass.getParseObjectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                parseObject.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item deleted from database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        else e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                // something went wrong
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.i("hereeeeeee1 === ", superCoolClass.getParseObjectId());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //no interenet
                }

            }
        });
```

In the second row, when I print the parseObjectId, instead of getting an Id associated with Parse, I get a timestamp representing the current time (it changes every time I run the code), resulting in a Parse Exception of "no results found for query"

Comment: In your second class where are you created superCoolClass Object and also add your SuperCoolClass

Comment: I solved the issue, I was missing a parameter in a different constructor call in a separate file.